# Center and resize image of any size to div wrapper using css?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a square div holding an img element.

The square div is 40 by 40.  The image is 160 by 80.

If I simply set the size on the div to be 40 by 40, the image would be resized to 40 by 20.  I want it to be sized to the length of the shortest length (80), resized (80 by 40) and then centered (i.e. so inside the 40x40 div you would have a resized img (80x40) with the x coordinates 20 to 60 showing)

Of course, if the image was 80 by 160 then the new image would be 40 by 80. Centered on y = [20, 60].

Note: In my case, I know the dimensions of my div, and it is square.  I do not know the dimensions of the image.  It would be awesome if the solution would also work for any dimensions (nonsquare and unknown) of the div, too.

Comment: I dont know about css. But you can do this with javascript and its not to hard. Did you have your mine set on css?

Comment: yea, I've seen people do some pretty advanced stuff with css. I'm almost sure someone will be able to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use background technique to display your image as you want

```
<div class="cropped img1"></div>
<style>
.img1 {background-image: url('http://megasite.net/yourimage.jpg');}
.cropped {width: 40px;height: 40px;background-position: center; background-size: cover;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible by CSS3 `background-size: cover;`

The image is rendered, preserving its intrinsic proportion, at the largest size contained within, or covering, the background positioning area.  If the image has no intrinsic proportion, then it is rendered at the size of the background positioning area.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size